# ADC conversion triggered by 1ms timer not working, STM32F4

Tags: timer, stm32, adc

Im using STM32F429 board and my ultimate goal is to get ADC conversion(set to deliver 2.7Ksps or 2.7 samples every 1ms) using TIM8 trigger, collect 1000 samples in buffer and do DMA transfer every second. I managed to get Timer running, but for some reason ADC conversion is not triggered. Without timer ADC is running well and DMA working (just not every 1ms, but faster).

APB2 Timers clock is 168Mhz.
APB2 Peripherals clock is 84Mhz.

TIM8 init function:

```
    void MX_TIM8_Init(void)
    {
```

```
    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
    TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig;
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;
    TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig;

    __HAL_RCC_TIM8_CLK_ENABLE();

    htim8.Instance = TIM8;
    htim8.Init.Prescaler = TIM_CLOCKPRESCALER_DIV8; // 1/(168MHz / 2^8) = 1.5238us
    htim8.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim8.Init.Period = 655;                        // 1.5238us * 656 = 0.999ms ~ 1ms
    htim8.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim8.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim8) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim8);

    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim8, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR1;
    if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim8, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim8) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim8, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TIMING;
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
    sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim8, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim8, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

}
```

ADC init function:

```
    void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
    {
```

```
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
    */
    hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
    hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2; // 84MHz / 2^6 = 1312.5 KHz
    hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T8_TRGO;
    hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
    hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
    hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
    if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK) {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
    */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_480CYCLES; // 1312.5KHz / 480cyc per sample = 2.7Ksps
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
    */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
    sConfig.Rank = 2;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_480CYCLES;
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

}
```

Main code:

```
    int main(void)
    {
        //MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------

        // Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick.
        HAL_Init();

        // Configure the system clock
        SystemClock_Config();

        // Initialize all configured peripherals

        MX_DMA_Init();
        MX_ADC1_Init();
        MX_TIM8_Init();

        HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)ADC_buf, ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH);

        DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM8_STOP); //Stop timer if code hit a breakpoint

     int timerValue = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            timerValue = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim8);
            if (halfConvFlag != false)
            {
                println ("Half Conversion callback");
                halfConvFlag = false;
            }
           else if (fullConvFlag != false)
            {
                println ("Full Conversion callback");
                fullConvFlag = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

When debugging, `__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER` gives me the count that proves it is working, but `ADC_buf` is not collecting any values. What am I missing, clock configurations should be correct 2 channels, 2 samples per ms and timer is close to 1ms. I generated the timer configuration using STM32CubeMX.

Comment: I got the timer working finally. I changed few things: 1. sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET; changed to sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
2. Changed location of HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim8); from TIM8 init to main, right before HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)ADC_buf, ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH);

Comment: Are you sure that you are really using the timer because from your code it seems that you just use the continous_conversion_mode and changed the sampling_rate to fit your needs. I mean thanks for the workaround, im also having trubble triggering the ADC with a timer :D