# ADC conversion triggered by timer not working, STM32L4

Tags: timer, stm32, adc, stm32cubemx

I'm working on the ADC , conversion triggered by  timer2 , but there is no output. APB2 Timers clock is 80Mhz. Only 1 ADC channel. ADC clock is also 80Mhz.  ADC conversion is triggered by 3.3us.  Controller is STM32L452.  Ignore Timer3.

Please let me know where I'M WRONG.

ADC+TIMER2+DMA

```
#define BUFFERSIZE   (50U)
static uint32_t adc_buf[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};


/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

void SystemClock_Config(void);

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

static void MX_DMA_Init(void);

static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);

static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);

static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);

void HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim);





/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */

  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */

  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */

  MX_GPIO_Init();


  MX_TIM3_Init();

  MX_ADC1_Init();

  MX_TIM2_Init();

  MX_DMA_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */


  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, adc_buf, BUFFERSIZE);

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{


  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;


    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */

RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 20;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */


     RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                  |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_PLLSAI1;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Source = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1M = 1;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1N = 16;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1P = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Q = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1R = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1ClockOut = RCC_PLLSAI1_ADC1CLK;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

      HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO1, RCC_MCO1SOURCE_SYSCLK, RCC_MCODIV_1);

        /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
        */
      if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

        /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
        */
      HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

        /**Configure the Systick 
        */
      HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

      /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
    }

    /* ADC1 init function */
    static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
    {



        /**Common config 
        */
      hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
      hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
      hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
      hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
      hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
      hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
      hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
      hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
      hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
      hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
      hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIG_T2_TRGO;
      hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
      hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
      hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
      hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
      if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }



        /**Configure Regular Channel 
        */
      sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
      sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
      sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_2CYCLES_5;
      sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
      sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
      sConfig.Offset = 0;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

    }

    /* TIM2 init function */
    static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
    {

      TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
      TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

      __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();;

      htim2.Instance = TIM2;
      htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
      htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
      htim2.Init.Period = 267;
      htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
      htim2.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
    //  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

      sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
      if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

      sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
      sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

    }

    /* TIM3 init function */
    static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
    {

      TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
      TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
      TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

      htim3.Instance = TIM3;
      htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
      htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
      htim3.Init.Period = 2000;
      htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;

      if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

      sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
      if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

      if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

      sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
      sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

    //  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TIMING;
    //  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
    //  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    //  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }

      HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

    }

    /** 
      * Enable DMA controller clock
      */
    static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
    {
      /* DMA controller clock enable */
      __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

      /* DMA interrupt init */
      /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

    }

    /** Configure pins as 
            * Analog 
            * Input 
            * Output
            * EVENT_OUT
            * EXTI
         PA8   ------> RCC_MCO
    */
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
    {

      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

      /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DEBUG_LED_Pin;
       GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
       GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
       GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
       HAL_GPIO_Init(DEBUG_LED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /*Configure GPIO pin : PA8 */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_MCO;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG_ADC_CONTROL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);


    }

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

    void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
    {
        if (htim->Instance == htim3.Instance)
        {
            /* Toggle LED */
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(DEBUG_LED_GPIO_Port, DEBUG_LED_Pin);
        }
    }

    void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
    {

      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
      if(hadc->Instance==ADC1)
      {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

      /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
        /* Peripheral clock enable */
        __HAL_RCC_ADC_CLK_ENABLE();

        /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration    
        PA0     ------> ADC1_IN5 
        */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG_ADC_CONTROL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        /* ADC1 DMA Init */
        /* ADC1 Init */
        hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA1_Channel1;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_0;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
        hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
        hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
        hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
        hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;

        if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
        {
          _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
        }

        __HAL_LINKDMA(hadc,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

      /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

      /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
      }

    }
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631642/adc-conversion-triggered-by-1ms-timer-not-working-stm32f4)

Comment: htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0; try to give any number but 0 to prescaler to receive interrupt  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 1 or 2 or else ;

Comment: At this frequency you won't see the LED changing as the switching frequency is to high. You might also run into trouble as the interrupt might take longer than the period to the next interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

firstly  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0; try to give any number but 0 to prescaler to receive interrupt  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 1 or 2 or else;
Secondly in your callback you are checking timer 2

```
   void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance == htim3.Instance)
    {
        /* Toggle LED */
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(DEBUG_LED_GPIO_Port, DEBUG_LED_Pin);
    }
}
```

I propose you to check timer2 because you are initializing  the timer2 in your code which is  //HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);

```
   void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance == TIM2)
    {
        /* Toggle LED */
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(DEBUG_LED_GPIO_Port, DEBUG_LED_Pin);
    }
}
```